# Can function in module.exports access global variable in module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

If I have code like this in one module,

```
var foo = "bar";

module.exports = function() {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

and I access it from another like so,

```
var mod = require('above-module');
mod();
```

Will it be able to access the variable 'foo' which is local to the module or is it out of scope after 'require' has cached the exported function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do this.  Typically questions like this are frowned upon because they can be answered more quickly by just trying it out.  You'll get your answer faster that way too

Update based on comments:

## Scenario 1 (no errors)

Say you have two modules, module A and module B

**module A**

```
var foo = "bar";

module.exports = function() {
    console.log(foo);
}
```

**module B**

```
var mod = require('A');
mod();
```

If module B is run, "bar" will be logged in the console.  If you attempt to access module A's foo directly from another module, you will get errors because foo is out of scope.

## Scenario 2 (undefined errors)

If you try to access foo from module A in another module, there will be errors

**module C**

```
var mod = require('A');
console.log(foo);  //error.  undefined.  foo is out of scope here
console.log(mod.foo);  //also an undefined error
```

## Scenario 3 (Redefining A to allow foo access outside module)

If you need to have foo accessible outside module A, it needs to be exported.  Simplest way to do that would be to add it as a property to the exported function

**Redefined module A**

```
var foo = "bar";
module.exports = function() {
    console.log(foo);
}

module.exports.foo = foo;
```

Then you could access like so

**module Accessing foo**

```
var mod = require('A');
var foo = mod.foo;  //access foo in module A like so
```

Comment: Yes, and if *YOU* had tried it out you would have realized that `foo` is no global variable, but a very local one to the first module. So, your answer is completely wrong, hence -1.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but I read it like, will the following javascript "work" if the two code samples are in different modules.  As it is written that javascript will work.  If OP had done something like var modFoo = foo or var modFoo = mod.foo then the answer would be no you can't do that

Comment: If you are interested in helping the OP, you might as well add another answer explaining your comment.  Much more helpful then pointing out everything that is wrong

Comment: There is some confusion about what you are asking.  Please see my edit to see if that answers your question.