# Reset required variable to initial value

Tags: javascript

Okay since my initial post was confusing I just made a minimal example:

data.js contains:

```
exports.store = {
  "banana": "fresh",
  "apple":  "rotten"
}
```

server.js contains:

```
var data = require("./data.js");
var dataInitial = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

exports.changeData = function(){
  data.store.banana = "rotten";
}

exports.resetData = function(){
  data = dataInitial;
};
```

server.test.js contains:

```
var server = require("./server.js");

test("test reset data", () =>{
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  server.changeData();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  server.resetData();
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

If I set this up as a node program using jest to run server.test.js I get  "ReferenceError: data is not defined". Why do I get this error? How can I accomplish what I want to do?

Comment: .....just duplicate the initial variable?

Comment: sounds to me that you want to copy and modify the initial store object for each test. To do a deep copy of an object you can use `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myObject))`

Comment: Ok, so I tried this: in server.js I have got 

var data = require('./data.js');
var dataInitial = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));

at the top and then server.js contains the function 

exports.resetDataForTests = function(){
  data = dataInitial;
};

which I then call after a test in server.test.js via server.resetDataForTests(); 

If I run my test then I get:  "ReferenceError: data is not defined". This is not the behaviour I expect if I follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878005/can-function-in-module-exports-access-global-variable-in-module.

Comment: I have literally no idea what your asking

Answer (score 1):

You could do `exports.store = function(){return 'JSON DATA'}` and call it after you require it, or make a copy of the data each time before modifying it.